# why would loadfactor be 0.75

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I am reading this from javadoc for [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

The table is dynamically expanded when there are too many collisions (i.e., keys that have distinct hash codes but fall into the same slot modulo the table size), with the expected average effect of maintaining roughly two bins per mapping (corresponding to a 0.75 load factor threshold for resizing).

If it is two bins per mapping (key->value), then wouldn't the load factor be 0.5, other than 0.75?

Comment: FWIW, the description is very poorly written - having "a 0.75 load factor threshold for resizing" means "the table is dynamically expanded" when the number of stored elements is > 0.75 time the number of slots/buckets, which actually is subtly different from "when there are too many collisions" - you might still have 0 collisions, or every existing element might collide.

Comment: Further, re "collisions (i.e., keys that have distinct hash codes but fall into the same slot modulo the table size)" - a collision is a collision whether the hash codes were the same or not... that distinction is meaningful to whether a resize might remove the collision though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-trivial cost to splitting the bins which is amortized across the entire runtime of the `Map`. The target threshold (after resize) **is** 0.5. But, the trigger threshold to split the bins is 0.75 (presumably because 0.75 is 0.5+(0.5/2), 50% greater). The required number of bins is dependent on the number of collisions and the efficiency of the `hashCode()` algorithm but the assumption is that collisions are rare (because the `hashCode()` distributes the keys well).

Comment: Right kind of perspective, but your "The target threshold (after resize) is 0.5." clashes with "expected *average* effect of maintaining roughly two bins per mapping", which implies a post-resize load of considerably *less* than 0.5 is needed for 0.5 to end up the average.